# Search Crystal Reports in Visual Studio and determine whether SQL table/proc is being used

Tags: visual-studio-2008, search, crystal-reports

Hello I have a number of crystal reports in my VS2008 project.

I am making a change to a couple of my database tables and want to ensure that I make all the necessary changes to the reports. I have done a standard VS search for the specific stored procedure that is being used and it found no results. However, when I went into a report and looked at the "Select Expert" I saw that the procedure is in fact being used.

Is there a way to easily search all the reports for this procedure (and others)? Or do I have to go into every single report and check?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of the VB proc I built to generates the list of all tables used by my reports. Reports are listed in a 'reports Table', and I use a memo field to store the name of all used tables. It is then quite easy to update all requested reports once tables have been modified.

```
Public function tablesUsedByAReport(myReportName as string) as string
Dim m_report As CRAXDRT.Report, _
      m_crystal As CRAXDRT.Application, _
      m_tablesUsedByAReport As String

Dim m_table As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable, _
      m_section As CRAXDRT.section, _
      m_objet As Object, _
      m_subReport As CRAXDRT.SubreportObject

Set m_crystal = New CRAXDRT.Application
Set m_rapport = m_crystal.OpenReport(m_nomRapport, 1)

'table names in the report'
For Each m_table In m_rapport.Database.tables
    m_tablesUsedByAReport = m_tablesUsedByAReport & m_table.location & ";"
Next m_table

'table names in each of the subreports'
For Each m_section In m_rapport.Sections
    For Each m_objet In m_section.ReportObjects
        If m_objet.Kind = crSubreportObject Then
            Set m_subReport = m_objet
            Set m_report = m_subReport.OpenSubreport
            For Each m_table In m_rapport.Database.tables
                m_tablesUsedByAReport = m_tablesUsedByAReport & m_table.location & ";"
           Next m_table
        End If
    Next m_objet
Next m_section

'my tables list'
tablesUsedByAReport = m_tablesUsedByAReport

End function
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with reporting services reports. I ended using a freeware app named [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/download.aspx) . I'm sure that there are lots of tools that do the same thing, but this is what I use. I just point it to a folder and put the table name I'm looking for in the "containing text field". I pull of my source from TFS into my VS projects folder and it doesn't take this app long to search all sub directories and it always seems to find what I need. It's not integrated into VS, but it may be worth a shot if no one provides a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I modified Philippe's code to this:

```
Public Function tablesUsedByAReport(ByRef report As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass) As String

    Dim m_tablesUsedByAReport As String = String.Empty

    Dim myTables As Tables = report.Database.Tables

    'table names in the report'
    For Each myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In myTables
        m_tablesUsedByAReport = m_tablesUsedByAReport & myTable.Location & ";"
    Next
    For Each subreport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument In report.Subreports
        For Each mytable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In subreport.Database.Tables
            m_tablesUsedByAReport = m_tablesUsedByAReport & mytable.Location & ";"
        Next
    Next
    Return m_tablesUsedByAReport

End Function
```